# Enabling and configuring InnoDB on MAMP

Tags: mysql, innodb, mamp

I'm trying to change the InnoDB settings on my MAMP installation and having no luck. The InnoDB settings in MAMP's my.cnf are all commented out by default. So after stopping MySQL, copying the appropriate log files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile_1,libdata), and then uncommenting the InnoDB settings in my.cnf, I try starting MySQL without success.

Most of the databases in my installation are Drupal 7 sites with InnoDB tables, and the MySQL under MAMP is running dreadfully slow. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?